# Sesión inactiva + refresh

Tags: php, html, refresh

Espero puedan ayudarme un poco con este código que estoy manejando, en mi portal trato de que tenga un tiempo de inactividad (este para finas prácticos el tiempo de inactividad que tiene son 5 segundos). Como tal el código funciona de la forma en que quiero, el problema surge cuando al terminar el tiempo de inactividad el portal no se refresca automáticamente esto para que me saque del portal y tenga que volver acceder (cuestiones de seguridad); ya intente varios métodos pero ninguno me ha funcionado, el mas reciente que estoy ocupando es el siguiente:

```
<?php 
//INACTIVIDAD
if (!isset($_SESSION['tiempo'])) {
  $_SESSION['tiempo'] = time();
  //Comparación para redigir página, si la vida de sesión sea mayor al timepo insertado en inactivo.
} else if (time() - $_SESSION['tiempo'] > 5) {

  date_default_timezone_set('America/Mexico_City');

  $hoy = date("Y-m-d");
  $nomusuario = $_SESSION['user'];

  $horaInicio = $_COOKIE["tiempo"];
  $horaFin = date("H:i");
  $tiempo = abs(strtotime($horaFin) - strtotime($horaInicio));
  $tiempoTotal = ($tiempo / 60 . " Minutos");

  $ti = "insert into tiemposesion(Consultor, HoraInicio, HoraFin, tiempoTotal, fecha)
            values ('$nomusuario','$horaInicio','$horaFin', '$tiempoTotal', '$hoy')";
  $inserT = mysqli_query($conexion, $ti);
 
  //Removemos sesión.
  session_unset();
  //Destruimos sesión.
  session_destroy();

  $page = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
  $sec = "5";
   //Redirigimos pagina.
  header("Refresh: $sec; url=$page; location:index.php");
  exit();
}

// Activamos sesion tiempo.
$_SESSION['tiempo'] = time();

date_default_timezone_set('America/Mexico_City');
$fecha = date("H:i");
setcookie("tiempo", $fecha);

?>
```

Pero sigo presentando el mismo problema, la versión de php que manejo es a 7.3.33 igual descubrí que con la etiqueta de html `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5">` podría funcionar pero cada 5 segundos la página se refresca y comienza un ciclo infinito.

Comment: Esto no lo podrás hacer con PHP puro. Creo que necesitas manejar la actividad del usuario con Javascript o alguna de sus implementaciones. Mira [esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/q/667555/1545868) y sus respuestas (en inglés)

Comment: Recuerda que PHP se ejecuta unicamente en el servidor. Entonces en este caso solo te saca cuando refrescas la pagina (y vuelves a acceder al servidor)... Si quieres que te saque a los 5 segundos mientras la página está cargada, debes manejarlo desde el lado de javascript.

Comment: Igual ya lo intente con Javascript, tal ves no de la manera correcta porque sigo presentando el mismo problema, debido a que caigo en un ciclo infinito, porque aunque detecte que el portal tiene actividad el código del Javascript se sigue ejecutando y esto se ve reflejado en el portal ya que cada 5 segundos se muestra el refresh.

Comment: Pero a que le llamas "actividad"??? Porque si el usuario hace scroll a la página podría considerarse actividad, pero con http-equiv="refresh" te va a actualizar igual

Comment: Con solo interactuar en el portal sin que el mouse este detenido lo considera actividad, y en efecto ejecutar el http-equiv="refresh" se actualiza y eso es lo que quiero evitar. De antemano muchas gracias por las respuestas.